# Why do people bother with the ice when making a martini?

Tags: cocktails, vodka, gin, recipes

You could just keep your vodka/gin in the freezer, and mix it with vermouth. Why do people bother with the ice when making a martini? Ice just waters it down -- and if you do wish to dilute your drink, you can just add water to it.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Dry Martini or cold gin?](https://alcohol.stackexchange.com/questions/7927/dry-martini-or-cold-gin)

Comment: @d4zed This question is about **ice** though, not how little **vermouth** you can use and still call it a "martini".

Comment: The water, that is melted while stirring, is quite an important part of making a good Dry Martini. It helps smoothen the alcohol and changes the texture of the cocktail (alcohol, water and the mixture of both has a different viscosity)

Comment: @d4zed Your comment is an adequate answer. You should post it as such.

Answer (score 5):

The water, that is melted while stirring, is quite an important part of making a good Dry Martini. It helps smoothen the alcohol and changes the texture of the cocktail (alcohol, water and the mixture of both has a different viscosity)

Comment: You could just add water.

Comment: Well it wouldn't be cold, then. If you put gin and vermouth in the freezer beforehand, you could just add water, yes. Probably the most unromantic Martini ever.

Comment: I think your last comment is relevant. The process of making a martini is part of the appeal, especially if shaken.

Comment: @EricS So the whole thing with the ice is just for show... **d4zed** Maybe you should've put that in the answer.

Comment: @bobcat Seems like a good time to try an experiment. Try making with and without ice and report back with your impressions.